# WPF: How to display a number as a bitfield of checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I was looking for a way to store a number as a property of an object and display its bit pattern as a sequence of checkboxes in Windows Presentation Foundation. This is the approach I am using now, which has the number value update when the checkboxes are checked, and the checkboxes update when the number changes. Please let me know if this could be achieved in a simpler way.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Media;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace WPF_Interface_Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public BitField BF { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            BF = new BitField(0, 32);
        }

        private void Plus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (BF.Value < uint.MaxValue)
                BF.Value += 1;
        }

        private void Minus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (BF.Value > uint.MinValue)
                BF.Value -= 1;
        }

        private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            var a = (CheckBox)sender;
            int checkity = 0;
            if (a.IsChecked.Value)
                checkity = 1;
            BF.Value = BF.Value | (uint)(checkity << (int)a.Tag);
        }
    }
    public class Bit : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool state;
        public bool State { get { return state; } set { if (this.state != value) { this.state = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("State"); } } }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public Bit()
        {
            State = false;
            Index = 0;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName) { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); }
    }
    public class BitField : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private uint value;
        public uint Value { get { return value; } set { if (this.value != value) { this.value = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Value"); UpdateValues(); } } }
        public byte ByteSize { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Bit> Values { get; set; }
        public BitField(uint givenValue, byte givenByteSize)
        {
            Value = givenValue;
            ByteSize = givenByteSize;
            Values = new ObservableCollection<Bit>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ByteSize; i++)
            {
                if ((Value | (uint)(1 << i)) == Value)
                    Values.Add(new Bit { State = true, Index = i });
                else
                    Values.Add(new Bit { State = false, Index = i });
            }
        }
        private void UpdateValues()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Values.Count; i++)
            {
                if ((Value | (uint)(1 << i)) == Value)
                    Values[i].State = true;
                else
                    Values[i].State = false;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName) { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Interface_Tests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Interface_Tests"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,201,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=BF.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button x:Name="Minus" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,229,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Click="Minus_Click" />
        <ListBox x:Name="LBofChecks" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="186" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BF.Values, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=State, Mode=TwoWay}" Tag="{Binding Path=Index}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button x:Name="Plus" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,229,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Click="Plus_Click" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My approach involves using a novel `BitField` object as a property of the main window. I set `DataContext = this` and then construct the `BitField` property.

`BitField` notifies when its `Value` property changes. The `Value` property stores the number representing the sequence of bits. For the list of values to use as properties to bind to the checkboxes, I give `BitField` an `ObservableCollection<Bit> Values` property. The collection of `Bit` objects also has each object notify when their `State` bool property changes. I also store in each `Bit` the `Index` that the `Bit` object is inside the `ObservableCollection<Bit> Values`. You can see that in the `CheckBox` template in the .xaml file, I associate the `Tag` property of the checkboxes with the `Index` of their `Bit`.

Is there perhaps a simpler approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the ViewModel side of things I would just expose an integer/byte property for binding - e.g. int for 32 bit value. Call it "MyValue" for discussion. Yes, still notify when it changes.

On the View side, I would two way bind the "IsChecked" property of each Checkbox right to MyValue. For the "bit" binding you would use a converter, e.g. call it `BinaryValueToBitConverter`.

The converter takes an int (or byte etc.) and converts it to true false for each Checkbox. The key is that for each Checkbox you use the Checkbox's bit position as the `ConverterParameter` and the converter's Convert() method just does:

```
return (value & (1 << bitParam)) != 0;
```

Where "bitParam" is the passed ConverterParameter (of course).

You could probably find a way to use the CheckBox's child index of its parent control e.g. StackPanel/ListBox as the ConverterParameter.

Hope Helpful

Comment: Each checkbox represents a certain option. The bits and the options are of course ordered in a certain way according to the number representation. How would I change the order of options in the parent control without altering the meaning of the options? Is there an approach besides using an novel object or extending the checkbox object or using the Tag of the checkbox instead of the order in the parent control? Of those options, I would use the Tag of the checkbox to determine its corresponding bit position.

Comment: I didn't use a converter because what would I do for ConvertBack()? Ah, I see, I would need to use the existing number in both situations. Nevermind.